# Recover settings.json VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally `git clean`'d my .vscode directory including some (fairly complex) settings files.

After making the mistake I noticed that my settings were still applied in the editor. Can I extract them by opening up the developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it, though the problem is that changing the settings file will also update the memory representation in the running Code instance.

Anyway, to get to the config via debugger:

1. Open the problems panel in Code (View > Problems)
2. Open developer tools (Help > Toggle Developer Tools)
3. Click on Sources tab and Ctrl/Cmd+O to open `markersPanel.ts`
4. Find calls to `configurationService.getConfiguration()` and add breakpoints (it should be in a method called `autoReveal`
5. Inspect the `conf` object

Note that this one contains all settings, including the defaults. But it might be helpful to recover some of your changes.